# Springboot Restful API XML response root element shown as List

Tags: xml, rest, spring-boot, jackson

I'm trying to return a list of surveys in the form of XML response. I'm able to get below response:

```xml
<List>
    <item>
        <title>My Favorite Survey</title>
        <description>Description of the Survey</description>
        <surveyId>Survey1</surveyId>
        <questions>
            <question>...</question>
            <question>...</question>
        </questions>
    </item>
</List>
```

However, I wanted to show response as below:

```xml
<surveys>
    <survey>
        <title>My Favorite Survey</title>
        <description>Description of the Survey</description>
        <surveyId>Survey1</surveyId>
        <questions>
            <question>...</question>
            <question>...</question>
        </questions>
    </survey>
</surveys>
```

Here is my POJO class:

```java
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName="survey")
public class Survey {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "surveyId")
    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String description;

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "questions")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "question")
    private List<Question> questions;
    // getters and setters

}
```

Controller class:

```java
@RestController    
class SurveyController {
    @Autowired
    private SurveyService surveyService;

    @GetMapping(path = "/surveys")
    public List<Survey> retrieveQuestions() {
        return surveyService.retrieveAllSurveys();
    }
}
```

Seems like `@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName="survey")` is not working in my case and what can I do for list to display as Surveys. Please guide me on how can I use my custom tag name in place of List and item.

Answer (score 0):

For XML content I recommend to write an XSD and then generate the JAXB classes using the following Maven Plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <generatePackage>com.mycompany.myproject.jaxb</generatePackage>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>                                 
    <configuration>
        <args>
            <arg>-mark-generated</arg>
        </args>
        <locale>en</locale>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```